# how to determine where a user clicked at on an ImageButton via Android?

Tags: android, imagebutton, motionevent

this is my ImageButton. my confusion is that i do not know how to determine whether the user clicked on the Login half, or the Sign up half, so i can take them to the respective Activity. i would be incredibly grateful if somebody can 1) name a resource i can use to learn on my own, or 2) explain the process of finding view locations and any possible algorithms used to determine if a click was in bounds of a specific portion of a View or not.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have 2 image buttons and try to achieve the same look and feel you want.

In your case, even though this kind of thing is doable. It is expensive and complicated and unnecessary. And you will have problems with styling of the buttons (eg: focus)

Edit:

Yes I understand, But I suggest you not to over complicate things. Because, your device has limited resources (eg: battery),

But you can still get the experience on how to create a circle like button with two sides on it, using 2 buttons which is still exciting :D.

Comment: thankyou @Diyoda. sometimes the most important thing is to learn what not to do.

Answer (score 3):

You should divide your button into 2 different ones, and process clicks separately.